# How to get the raw numeric HTML representation of special characters?

Tags: r, regex, encoding, special-characters

When I type `"\xfc"` into R it leads to `[1] "ü"`. I don't want that, I want this to lead to `[1] "\xfc"`. I also do not really understand why `Encoding("\xfc")` is `"latin1"` although I changed the settings in Code->Saving to UTF-8. I want to write a function that replaces some special characters like `"ü"` by `"\xfc"` but I can't achieve this:

```
> stringr::str_replace_all("Müller", "ü", "\xfc")
[1] "Müller"
> stringr::str_replace_all("Müller", "ü", "\\xfc")
[1] "Mxfcller"
> stringr::str_replace_all("Müller", "ü", "\\\xfc")
[1] "Müller"
> stringr::str_replace_all("Müller", "ü", "\\\\xfc")
[1] "M\\xfcller"
```

What I really want is `[1] "M\xfcller"`

(How) can I achieve this?

Comment: check out `?Quotes`, it seems like R interprets `"\xnn"` as character with the hexcode `nn`. I do not know if there is a workaround for this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

The last line gives the result you want. The backslash is escaped when the string is printed. To see that, let's save the string to file and then see the content of the file.

```r
s <- stringr::str_replace_all("Müller", "ü", "\\\\xfc")

writeLines(s, "test.txt")

cat(readLines("test.txt"))
#> M\xfcller
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Also see this GitHub issue: https://github.com/STAT545-UBC/Discussion/issues/394

Comment: `x <- readLines("test.txt")`. Now `x` is still `"M\\xfcller"`. I want to pass `x` to another function and `x` has to be `"M\xfcller"`

Comment: R treat strings a little bit differently. If you try `x = "M\xfcller"`, you get "Müller".

Comment: Also, you can see in the file that the string is `M\xfcller` but R *shows* it as `M\\xfcller`.

Comment: `s <- "a\b"` and `print(s)` leads to `"a\b"` und not `"a\\b"` so there must be a difference? Or am I wrong?

Comment: R doesn't interpret "\b" as a special character. Try "a\x" and you get an error about "hex digits" which is what "\xfc" is.